# Maximise the number of tokens in your hand

Tags: optimization, asymptotics, puzzle

Here's a puzzle about maximising long-term growth.

Say you have a "bank" which, at each time $t$ (a non-negative integer), contains a number of "tokens" $b_t$ (also a non-negative integer). At $t=0$, $b_0=1$ (i.e. we start with one token in the bank).

Now, at every turn, we can withdraw up to $b_t$ tokens from the bank, and add these to our "hand". The number of tokens remaining in the bank will **double** each turn. The number of tokens in our hand will not grow at all (unless we withdraw more).

The aim is to **find a withdrawal strategy which maximises the asymptotic growth rate of $h_t$,** the number of tokens in our hand. (Formally, this could be expressed with [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

Some rules:

- You **cannot return money** to the bank once it's been withdrawn (so don't take it all out!)
- You can only withdraw an integer value at each turn.
- You live for eternity, so we are not interested in maximising $h_t$ at any given turn, but rather maximising the **long-term growth rate** of $h_t$.

---

Here's an example strategy to illustrate the problem. The strategy is simple: every second turn, we withdraw half the tokens in the bank. Let's see what happens:

| Time $t$ | Bank $b_t$ | Hand $h_t$ |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 4 | 0 | withdraw 2 |
|  | 2 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 4 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 8 | 2 | withdraw 4 |
|  | 4 | 6 |  |
| 5 | 8 | 6 |  |
| 6 | 16 | 6 | withdraw 8 |
|  | 8 | 14 |  |
| 7 | 16 | 14 |  |
| 8 | 32 | 14 | withdraw 16 |
|  | 16 | 30 |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

At the end of turn $2n$, we have $h_{2n} = 2^{n+1} - 2$, so $h_t = 2^{t/2+1} - 2 = \sqrt{2}^{t+2} - 2$. Hence this strategy gives a growth rate of $h_t \sim \sqrt{2}^t$. Not bad, but it seems like we could do better by withdrawing less often.

**The challenge here is to strike the right balance** between letting the money grow in the bank, and withdrawing enough to see good growth in your hand. I'm interested in any comments & answers related to this problem, including example strategies and analyses, bounds, proofs of (non-)optimality, etc.

---

**Edit:** I originally came up with this because I was thinking of the most efficient way to encode integers of arbitrary size in binary. The connection is thus: $t$ is the number of bits used for encoding, $h_t$ is the number of integers you've encoded so far, while $b_t$ is the number of $t$-bit sequences that don't represent an integer (so they can be used to encode larger integers).

Comment: **Upper bound:** $h_t \leq 2^t$. This is because
1) $h_t \leq h_t + b_t$ and
2) $h_t + b_t \leq 2^t$, since the best strategy here is just to leave everything in the bank.

Comment: Suppose you always withdraw a portion $\epsilon b_t$ from you bank balance, where $0\le \epsilon < 1/2$. The growth rate for $h_{t}$ will be asymptotically $C\cdot [2(1-\epsilon)]^t$. This means that your asymptotic growth increases as $\epsilon$ gets closer to $0$, but $\epsilon=0$ is not viable since it gives zero growth for $h_t$. Therefore, there is no "best" strategy. Or really, the best strategy is just to leave all your money in the bank, and get a debit card.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: but what if you "tapered off" the withdrawal rate $\epsilon$ - maybe then it would be possible to make $b_t \sim 2^t$? However, you can't taper it too much, because we still want exponential growth in $h_t$.

Comment: I think you are right, by letting $\epsilon_t$ be a function of $t$ tending to zero, you can get growth like $2^t$, maybe with some sub-exponential factors. But the proof seems a little too involved for me to attempt.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I wrote a little Python script to generate a table based on a strategy:

```
# see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4450026
from prettytable import PrettyTable # https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/

# runStrategy runs the strategy for the given no. of turns
# strategy(t, bt, ht) -> how much to withdraw
def runStrategy(strategy, turns):
    table = PrettyTable(['Turn', 'Bank', 'Hand', ''])
    t = 0
    bt = 1
    ht = 0
    

    for i in range(turns+1):
        table.add_row([t, bt, ht, ''])
        withdraw = strategy(t, bt, ht)
        if withdraw > 0:
            bt -= withdraw
            ht += withdraw
            table.add_row(['', bt, ht, f'withdraw {withdraw}'])

        # Change variables for next round
        t += 1
        bt *= 2
    
    print(table)

# Given the turn number `t`, the current bank balance `bt`, and the current
# hand balance `ht`, strategy returns how much to withdraw this turn.
def strategy(t, bt, ht):
    # YOUR STRATEGY HERE
    if t % 2 == 0:
        return bt//2
    else:
        return 0

runStrategy(strategy, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of a general mathematical formalism, it seems more helpful to think of this in terms of a "withdrawal rate" $\varepsilon_t$ for each stage $t > 0$. i.e. at turn $t$, we withdraw $\varepsilon_t b_t$. If you work this through, we get

$$b_t = 2^t \cdot \prod_{i=1}^t (1-\varepsilon_i)$$

$$h_t = \sum_{i=1}^t \left( 2^i \varepsilon_i \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} (1-\varepsilon_j) \right)$$

As @MikeEarnest noted in a comment, if we have $\varepsilon_t$ constant, these reduce to

$$b_t = \big[ 2(1-\varepsilon) \big]^t$$

$$h_t = \frac{2\varepsilon}{1 - 2\varepsilon} \Big( \big[ 2(1-\varepsilon) \big]^t - 1 \Big) \sim \big[ 2(1-\varepsilon) \big]^t$$

But it seems like as long as $\varepsilon_t \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, we should be able to get $b_t \sim 2^t$. We still need to make sure that $\varepsilon_t \to 0$ slowly enough that we can still enjoy exponential growth in $h_t$.